# How do I set maximal jvm-memory (XMX) for a jar-file

Tags: java, jar, jvm

How do I set the maximal jvm-memory without adding an extra batch-script to my Programm.
Answer is provided below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a good question, but your implmenetation assumes a lot. I presume you have to document the name of your jar for your users to invoke "java -jar xyz.jar" on so can you also include in the documentation that "-Xmx256M" is required?

You may have more luck using a java launcher, such as [this one](http://www.redskaper.com/HowToRun.html) for Windows, where you put the launcher config (path, max memory etc.) in a separate file. For cross platform, there's LaunchAnywhere, and others, which function similarly. See [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)

To improve upon your existing scheme:

- use the `java.home` system property to resolve the location of the JDK/JRE
- use the `java.class.path` to set up the class path, and similarly for `java.library.path` if your application requires native code.
- pass command arguments passed to your main method to the spanwed process

But still, this seems to be a lot of effort that at best represents a leaky abstraction, when instead simple and clear documentation would suffice.