# What is a good way to deploy a Java program and give JVM arguments?

Tags: java, deployment, heap-memory, java-web-start

Currently I have been deploying my application as a .jar file, because users of every OS can just double click it. However I now need to increase the max heap size, and the only way to do that is to pass a command-line argument (-Xmx1g) to the JVM. I wish it was possible to include this in the jar manifest, but it's not.

So now I am forced to include a .bat or .csh with the .jar that has the arguments. It seems like there is a better way to do this right? I don't think that Webstart is a good option because the .jar is meant to run in a user's directory where it writes out files. The application is a desktop GUI app.

Comment: Looks like duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848346/how-do-i-set-maximal-jvm-memory-xmx-for-a-jar-file

Comment: *"I don't think that Webstart is a good option because the .jar is meant to run in a user's directory where it writes out files."*  Except for "run in a user's directory" (which is irrelevant nonsense, since a trusted JWS app. can read/write any file that is accessible by other Java apps.) JWS can do all that with one hand tied behind it's back.  Use [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to specify vmargs in the manifest file inside your jar, so you need a workaround like :

- Create a script that launch the jar file with specified vm args
- Wrap your jar inside an executable that will work as a launcher
- Compile your Java code into native binary

The first solution can be easily implement using a batch or an shell script for example, while for the second solution there are several alternatives that can be useful as for example the aforementioned and native [Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/) and [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) that is a Cross-platform Java executable wrapper. 
The third solution can be implemented in some situations and if your code is compatible with the [GNU classpath](http://www.gnu.org/software/classpath/) library, in this case you could compile into native binary using [GCJ](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/) .

Comment: Thanks. I decided to use the Launch4j tool to create an exe for windows users.

Answer (score 2):

Webstart seems like a good way to achieve that, and if you have the right permissions, nothing prevents you from reading from / writing to the user's file system.

It also provides several interesting "features", including:

- the possibility to push upgrades to the user transparently
- checking that the user is using the right version of the JRE

In your case, you would just need to use the following syntax:

```
<j2se version="1.7+" java-vm-args="-Xmx1g" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
```