# Increase JVM size for jar file

Tags: java

I am trying to increase the java heap size for jar file that launches easy neurons program.
There is a patch file that i tried to modify to be like that

```
java -jar easyNeurons.jar -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M
```

but I still get `VectorSizeMismatchException`

Comment: duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848346/how-do-i-set-maximal-jvm-memory-xmx-for-a-jar-file

Comment: @HemantMetalia no it is not there is no code to modify just jar file

Answer (score 0):

When a Java program runs out of memory, you get `OutOfMemoryException`, not `VectorSizeMismatchException`.

`VectorSizeMismatchException` indicates

> vector size does not match the network input or training element size

([see the docs](http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/neuroph/core/exceptions/VectorSizeMismatchException.html)).

Comment: Yes: Either it's a bug in the code or you'll need to check the inputs that you feed the software. If it's a bug, you'll need to look at the sources or report it to the company that sold you the product.