# How to set maximum JVM memory size (-Xmx) in my Java code?

Tags: java, memory, jar, jvm, command-prompt

I have a Java program which required **-Xmx1g** memory. I am using Netbeans IDE for application developing.  I can set this parameter from the IDE,

Right click on the project --> select 'set configuration' --> select 'customize' --> set 'VM option' to -Xmx1g

After setting Xmx value, programe works without any error.

But when I try to run the .jar file from the command prompt, it gives me OutOfMemory error.  So **I want to set this value in my Java code (e.g.: somewhere in the main method)** so I can run the .jar file from the command prompt.

How do I do that?

Comment: just use the command line parameters, thts all the configuration settings are doing in the background.

Comment: @JonTaylor can he call command line from java code and pass to it what ever ?!

Comment: no you add the parameters to the command which runs your jar file.

Comment: @shareef can you please tell me how to do this 'call command line from java code and pass to it'

Comment: @Jon what is the command line parameter? How do I use it in command line?

Comment: its exactly the same commands you use in the configuration, instead of just calling java -jar with the jar file you do this but add in the parameters you added in the IDE in configuration settings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848346/how-do-i-set-maximal-jvm-memory-xmx-for-a-jar-file

Comment: If the app. has a GUI, launch it using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  Memory requirements can be set in the launch file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, you can't do that in your java code as the jvm is already created when main get executed. But you still can use xmx switch from command line eg java -xmx1024m -jar (check the syntax, i did not).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the actual syntax, and I have tested it too.

java -jar -Xmx1024m [jar_file] [args]